# Bootstrap form's fields aren't showing correctly

Tags: bootstrap-4

I've been trying to develop a simple Bootstrap 4 form that has first and last name fields, among others, shown in the same row. I'm not sure why the label for Last Name looks like it's indented past the text field.

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="firstName" class="col-form-label col-4">First Name</label>
        <label class="col-form-label col-1"></label>
        <label for="lastName" class="col-form-label col-4">Last Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
       <input type="text" class="form-control col-4" id="firstName">
       <label class="col-form-label col-1"></label> <!-- Add a little bit of space between the text fields. -->
       <input type="text" class="form-control col-4" id="lastName">
    </div>
```

It looks like this:
[sample Bootstrap form with 2 labels and text fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x033B.jpg)

The only way that I could get the labels to not show like they're indented is to do something like this by adding the margin:

```
    <div class="form-group row">
       <label for="firstName" class="col-form-label col-4">First Name</label>
       <label class="col-form-label col-1"></label>
       <label for="lastName" class="col-form-label col-4">Last Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
       <input type="text" class="form-control col-4" id="firstName" style="margin-left: 10px;">
       <label class="col-form-label col-1"></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control col-4" id="lastName">
    </div>
```

I've tried adjusting the columns, but that didn't help at all. Is there a better way of making the labels aligned on top of the text fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the class "p-0" to your label elements that will solve your issue.

However I would suggest reviewing the form and rebuilding as the fundamentals are wrong. The above uses workarounds that aren't good practice and it wont be very mobile friendly either.

For example using labels as spacing and separating into 2 separate rows are both workarounds that aren't good practice.

For a better solution try using this code instead:

```
       <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-6">
         <label for="firstName" class="col-form-label col-12">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control col-12" id="firstName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
         <label for="lastName" class="col-form-label col-12">Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control col-12" id="lastName">
        </div>
       </div>
```

Here is the documentation if you would like to review futher: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/overview/